# Epicyclic Gear Train

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears

I'm working on a solution to this problem and I would like some advice and help. A fixed-ring epicyclic gear train is required to have an overall ratio of 5.5:1.

1. If the sun gear is to have between 10 to 15 teeth, suggest the most appropriate numbers of teeth for each of the constituent gears.
2. How many planet wheels would you propose for this design?

Comment: Please include any work that you have already done. This will help everyone to understand exactly what you are having trouble with.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a "[homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832)" (notice the quotation marks). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 2):

Start with 3 planets. Calculate the contact stresses and bearing loads. If too high then try 4 planets and repeat. Each individual planet will go down with more planets as you are sharing the load between them. Keep adding planets until you can either take the loads or you run out of room to add more. At that point, if you still can't take the load you probably need to up size the entire gearbox.